# How do I rewrite URLs that have GET variables in them?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that makes use of GET variables to determine what to display.

```
@session_start();
@extract($_GET);
@extract($_POST);
.
.
.
if (!$menu) { include("home.php"); }
if ($menu=='buy') { include("buy.php"); }
if ($menu=='invalidbuy') { include("invalidbuy.php"); }
if ($menu=='buydone') { include("buydone.php"); }
.
.
.
```

I think I have to make use of the .htaccess file to rename my URLs from "/index.php?menu=faq" to "/faq". How can I do this??

Comment: Using extract in this way is pretty short sighted. What if someone adds a parameter that conicides with a variable later on?

i.e. some code that says if($logged_in) {/* Do logged in stuff */}

user goes to script.php?logged_in=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to rewrite any request of a path like `/`*`foobar`* internally to `/index.php?menu=`*`foobar`*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

The additional [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) ensures that only non existing files (`!-f`) are rewritten.